# Is there a smart(er) way to "bounds check" a function pointer in plain C?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

**Backround information:**

When having a statemachine/dispatcher like so:

```
switch (var)
{
case 1:
  foo();
  var = 2;
  break;

case 2:
  bar();
  var = fuu();
  break;

case 3:
  foobar();
  var = 1;
  break;

default:
  var = 1;
  break;
}
```

the default case would always correkt `var` when it is not matching any of the exsiting cases.

Let's say I want to do the same by setting a functionpointer to point to either `foo()`, `bar()` or `foobar()`, according to my liking. Like so:

```
void (*fun_ptr)(void);

if (<some condition>)
{
  fun_ptr = foo;
}
else
{
  fun_ptr = bar;
}
```

and call the chosen function by said functionpointer like so:

```
fun_ptr();
```

**Question:**

The only way (I can think of), to validate if the functionpointer is indeed pointing to one of those given functions, is to manually go through a list of their addresses and checking if I find a match or set it to e.g. `foo` whenever I won't find one. I know that if the program does not manipulate the pointer in a wrong way there should not be a way that it is not pointing to one of the functions but lets assume there is the poisbility it changes.

Is there a more efficient/elegant way to do this?

Comment: What would the function pointer point to if not one of the valid functions?

Comment: Any other address and if you ask why should it there is no definitiv anser to that but that I can not let it unchecked.

Comment: What is the `a` in `case a:`?

Comment: What would you want to do in your current `default` case? Currently you are not calling anything then, but you are changing `var`. Calling an empty function would be easy, that could be a default function that does nothing (`void empty(){}`) or a function that aborts the program or whatever, but what about the `var`?

Comment: The whole question is pretty unclear and should be reworked. And maybe it's even an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: That seems rather the opposite of a state machine, in a state machine the task to be executed must be known without any ambiguity, it will carry out its task and move on to the next phase.

Comment: it may be a good idea to initialize `fun_ptr` to `NULL`. It will easily detect case when it's never set. Try `void (*fun_ptr)(void) = NULL;`

Comment: Well i guess the word statemachine is missleading here since it does not really matter for the questtion but i could come up with a better idea to explain my problem. But I will edit it so it makes more clear.

Comment: you could cast `fun_ptr` to `uintptr_t` and use as a key to a hashset to check if it belong to the good set.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error there is a reason ECC memory exists

Comment: This should be checked at compile time. Checking function pointers at runtime is probably too late to do anything about it. If you're worried about bit-flips, you're going to end up going down a deep paranoia rabbit hole where you can't even be sure that 1+1=2 any more. It might be 4611686018427387906.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what problem you want to solve. Why do you want to replace the `var` with `fun_ptr`? What possible error do you want to detect with the function pointer validation? An accidental modification of the pointer value? A wrong value (e.g. the address of a different function) assigned in the same way as it would be done with a correct value?

Comment: @tadman there is certain securety standards that are required for certification for people safety. I do trust my own program and tests that validate that there can't be a rational reason why the pointer could ever be direkting to 'nirvana' but it is how it is and for example said standart does not allow for arrey indexes that where not boundry checked priore to use. So it has nothing todo with paranoia or tin foil hat like thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard does not provide any means by which a function pointer can be tested to determine whether it points to one of a list of functions other than by comparing it individually to each function’s address. There is no relational operation (`<`, `<=`, `>=`, `>`) for functions or other operation that would do this.

You control every initialization and assignment of a pointer in your program and therefore can record at each point where an initialization or assignment occurs whether or not the pointer is being initialized or assigned to one of the functions of interest. This information can be recorded in a flag object (a Boolean or an integer given value 0 or 1), and then you can determine the pointer’s current status by testing the flag.

Going beyond the C standard, you might be able to arrange for the functions of interest to be located together in memory, and then you could apply relational tests on a pointer by converting it to `uintptr_t` to see if it is within the addresses spanned by the functions. The ability to do this depends on your linker and build tools and some aspects of your source code, such as whether the functions are defined in separate translation units. Generally, this approach is not worthwhile for a problem that can be solved as described above.

Comment: I do control every initialisation and assignement and still though for certification reasons I do have to do things like galpat ram test. That implys any acces to any ram cell could interfere with any other ram cell. Therefor I further have to double check idexes before using them for arreys and I assume double check a pointer to a function priore to calling it. Still though I am happy with your answer since when there is no better way of doing it than checking one by one than it is how it is.